# PuTTY not opening

Tags: windows-7, ssh, ftp, putty

PuTTY has stopped opening on my machine today. I've never had this problem before.

When I click on the .exe, PuTTY appears in the taskbar, but I cannot use it. It won't open. Like it's a frozen application or something.

I tried downloading a new version and the same thing happened. I tried downloading KiTTY and the same thing happened (see image). I can open FileZilla and Adobe etc so I don't think it's a permissions type thing or that .exe is suddenly blocked from opening. I can FTP using FileZilla as well.

It's a company machine and the OS is Windows Vista.

I'm not sure what to try next and no idea what the problem could be.

[image]

I should clarify, it's the configuration part of PuTTY that won't even open. PuTTY starts you off in that config section before you can proceed to the black box/window part.

Answer (score 0):

The program actually starts, so it appears to be an out-of-screen issue.

Right-click the program on the taskbar, and then click Move. Move the mouse pointer to the middle of the screen. Use the arrow keys (mostly LEFT !!!) on the keyboard to move the program window to a viewable area on the screen. Press enter.
Resize the window if required.

Alternately, you can extend your desktop (virtual mode) and find the out-of-resolution-range program.

Comment: Good suggestions. Thanks. 'Move' did nothing unfortunately. When I boot in safe mode I can launch PuTTY and see the config screen for it right in the middle of my monitor. But when I go back to normal mode, I still have the same problem!

Comment: I don't know how to find the out-of-resolution-range program. What is that?